# Whether to use conditional probability or Bayes theorem?

Tags: probability

I had found this question.

> A group of boys and girls know either French or Spanish. The number of boys and girls are in the ratio $1:4$. $30\%$ of the girls know Spanish and the rest of them know French. On the other hand, $50\%$ of the boys know Spanish and the rest of them know French. A student is chosen at random from the group of students who know Spanish. What is the probability that the chosen student is a girl?

My attempt was:

Let $P(G)$ and $P(B)$ be probability of choosing a girl and boy respectively. And $P(S)$ be probability of choosing someone who knows Spanish. Then,

> $P(G|S)= \frac{P(S|G)*P(G)}{P(S|G)*P(G)+P(S|B)*P(B)}$

But the answer using this way is not in the option. Moreover (B) is the answer in their answer key.

> (A) 2/7 
>     (B) 12/17 
>     (C) 20/41 
>     (D) 8/13

Is something wrong with my approach? How can I approach it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability of choosing a girl is $\frac{4}{5}$ probability that a girl  speaks Spanish is $\frac{4}{5}.\frac{3}{10}=\frac{12}{50}$  similarly probability of selecting a boy speaking Spanish is $\frac{1}{10}$ Thus using Bayes formula we get the answer as $\frac{12}{17}$

Answer (score 1):

It is IMV handsome to choose for $20$ boys and $80$ girls.

Then $24$ girls speak Spanish and $56$ girls speak French.

And $10$ boys speak Spanish and $10$ boys speak French.

So if a Spanish speaking student is chosen then the probability that it is a girl equals:$$\frac{24}{24+10}=\frac{24}{34}=\frac{12}{17}$$

---

Using your method I find:
$$P\left(G\mid S\right)P\left(S\right)=P\left(S\mid G\right)P\left(G\right)$$

with:

- $P\left(S\mid G\right)=\frac{3}{10}$
- $P\left(G\right)=\frac{4}{5}$
- $P\left(S\right)=P\left(S\mid B\right)P\left(B\right)+P\left(S\mid G\right)P\left(G\right)=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{5}+\frac{3}{10}\frac{4}{5}=\frac{17}{50}$

and again leading to $P\left(G\mid S\right)=\frac{12}{17}$.